# Posso colocar um array como parâmetro de outro array?

Tags: c, array, array-multidimensional

```
for(i=0; i<=203; i++){
  array2[3][i];

  array1[array2][2][string]; /*string corresponde a uma string ja definida e nao relevante para a questao*/

(...)
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você quer fazer for:

```
 for (i = 0; <= 203; i++) {
       array1[array2][2];
 }
```

Sim, você pode, desde que o valor de `array2` seja um inteiro. Não entendi o que você quer por `array1[array2][2][string]`, pois você não pode usar `string` como índice.

Detalhe: Se você está usando C, não existe tipo `string` em C, ficou um tanto nebuloso o que é essa variável `string` que você está usando.

Comment: Muito obrigada por todas as respostas. elucidaram imenso :)

Comment: @Pavlova você pode colocar uma das respostas como correta se te ajudou

Answer (score 1):

Esta sintaxe usada não faz muito sentido da forma apresentada e a terminologia que você está usando também não. O que você chama de parâmetro é o índice?

O que é esse `string`. É uma variável? Que tipo ela é? C não tem um tipo chamado *string*. Seria um `char *`?

`array1` tem três dimensões mesmo? É o que está mostrando.

Se for exatamente como você está colocando, **não é possível**.

## *Array* multidimensional

O que provavelmente está procurando é o *array* multidimensional. Funciona assim:

```
int a[3][4] = {  
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11}
};
```

Viu? São duas dimensões. Três linhas e quatro colunas.

Na verdade a organização da memória é *flat*, ou seja mesmo parecendo ter 3 linhas e 4 colunas, no fundo você tem 12 elementos no *array*. Tanto que você pode definir desta forma:

```
int a[3][4] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
```

No fundo quando for acessar é feito uma conta com os elementos das duas dimensões para achar o número do elemento. Normalmente é (linha escolhida * total de colunas + coluna escolhida). Então para acessar o elemento [1, 3] é feito a conta (1 * 4 + 3), portanto seria o elemento 7 (oitavo elemento).

Note que todos os elementos devem ser do mesmo tipo. É possível colocar elementos com tipos variados de uma outra forma, não com *array* multidimensional. Até é possível se o tipo for um ponteiro mas aí já vai complicando.

## Um elemento de *array* como índice.

É possível fazer algo assim:

```
array1[array2[3][i]][2][string] //estou considerando 3 dimensões e que string é um inteiro
//também estou considerando que array2 é de um tipo inteiro
```

O que está fazendo é pegar o elemento da linha 3 e coluna `i` do `array2` para determinar o elemento de `array1` a ser pego. É só fazer a conta demonstrada acima para ver qual elemento é. Mas isto é possível apenas se o elemento for do tipo `int` (ou quase isto, veja abaixo). Com "string" não dá, pelo menos não de forma simples assim (como *arrays* em C na verdade são ponteiros, dá para fazer algumas coisas criativas).

Pois bem, é possível fazer da forma demonstrada sim:

```
array1[array2][2][string] //estou considerando 3 dimensões e que string é um inteiro
```

Isto é o mesmo que dizer que está pegando:

```
array1[array2[0][0]][2][string] //estou considerando 3 dimensões e que string é um inteiro
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MultiDimentionalExample.c).

Então neste caso vai pegar o valor primeiro elemento do `array2` e usar como índice da linha de `array1`. Ele não está usando o *array* como índice mas o primeiro elemento de um *array*.

Muito provavelmente não é o que você quer.

## Índices devem ser inteiros

Em C **não é possível ter índices de qualquer tipo. Eles são limitados à tipos inteiros**. O mais comum é usar `int`, mas nada impede o uso de outro inteiros. Há quem prefira usar `size_ t`.

Se sua intenção é realmente usar uma *string* como índice teria que usar outra notação, usar ponteiros direto e fazer uma implementação que lide com isto. Mas quando fizer isto não estará trabalhando com *arrays* e sim com outra estrutura de dados que coleciona elementos.

Em C++ é possível dar a ilusão sintática de índice usando *string*. Ainda assim não será mais um *array*.